# How can I disable changing tabs in a QTabWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5.13

I have a QTabWidget with multiple tabs. I want to disble the tabwidget itself so that the user cannot change the current tab, but the contents of the current tab have to stay enabled. How can I achive this in Qt?

If I disable the entire QTabWidget, the contents of the current tab will get disabled as well, which I don't want.

I also tried to disable all but the current tab, but this only disables the other tabs' contents. The other tabs themselves can still be opened.

Comment: You might try to override the `QTabWidget::changeEvent()` function and ignore events?

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I found a solution myself after looking into the docs of QTabWidget and how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more research and found a solution, what I want is to disable the `tabBar` of my `QTabWidget`, like this:

```
ui->mytabWidget->tabBar()->setEnabled(false);
```